# Need help on SLDS with LWC

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system, lightning-web-components, slds

I am trying to implement the Custom Date Range Picker using Lightning Web Component Framework.

[image: Custom Date Range Picker]

My Code is allowing to select start Date and End Date and it is also highlighting the days in between the both start and End Date.

Only multiple days selected look is missing. which should be something like below:

[image: Example from SLDS]

Link to SLDS DatePickers Example: https://lightningdesignsystem.com/components/datepickers/#site-main-content

Below is the code.

**HTML File:**

```
    <template>
    <lightning-card class="slds-card_boundary">
        <div aria-hidden="false" class="slds-datepicker" role="dialog" data-id="grid">
            <div class="slds-datepicker__filter  slds-grid ">
                <div class="slds-datepicker__filter_month slds-grid slds-grid_align-spread slds-grow">
                    <div class="slds-align-middle">
                        <lightning-button-icon icon-name="utility:left" variant="bare" alternative-text="Previous Month"
                            size="medium" onclick={goToPreviousMonth} class="no-focus" icon-class="no-focus">
                        </lightning-button-icon>
                    </div>
                    <h2 id="month" class="slds-align-middle" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">{monthName}</h2>
                    <div class="slds-align-middle">
                        <lightning-button-icon icon-name="utility:right" variant="bare" alternative-text="Next Month"
                            size="medium" onclick={goToNextMonth} class="no-focus" icon-class="no-focus">
                        </lightning-button-icon>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slds-shrink-none">
                    <select class="slds-select" onchange={handleYearChange} data-id="yearId">
                        <template iterator:it={options}>
                            <option key={it.value.value} value={it.value.value} selected={it.value.selected}>
                                {it.value.label}
                            </option>
                        </template>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <table data-id="maintable" aria-labelledby="month" aria-multiselectable="true"
                class="slds-datepicker__month" role="grid">
                <thead>
                    <tr id="weekdays">
                        <template iterator:it={weekNameArray}>
                            <th scope="col" class="dayOfWeek" key={it.value}>
                                <abbr title={it.value}>{it.value}</abbr>
                            </th>
                        </template>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                    <template iterator:it={dAW}>
                        <tr data-id={it.value.name} key={it.value.name} class={it.value.trClass}>
                            <template iterator:it1={it.value.days}>
                                <td class={it1.value.tdClass} aria-disabled={it1.value.ariaDisabled}
                                    aria-selected={it1.value.ariaSelected} key={it1.value.key} role="gridcell"
                                    onclick={handleCellClick}>
                                    <span data-id={it1.value.key} data-value={it1.value.value}
                                        data-disabled={it1.value.ariaDisabled} class="slds-day">{it1.value.label}</span>
                                </td>
                            </template>
                        </tr>
                    </template>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <lightning-button class="slds-align_absolute-center" variant="base" label="Today" title="Today"
                onclick={goToToday}></lightning-button>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

**JavaScript File:**

```
import { LightningElement, track } from "lwc";
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
const l10n = {
    weekdays: {
        shorthand: ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"],
        longhand: [
            "Sunday",
            "Monday",
            "Tuesday",
            "Wednesday",
            "Thursday",
            "Friday",
            "Saturday"
        ]
    },
    months: {
        shorthand: [
            "Jan",
            "Feb",
            "Mar",
            "Apr",
            "May",
            "Jun",
            "Jul",
            "Aug",
            "Sep",
            "Oct",
            "Nov",
            "Dec"
        ],
        longhand: [
            "January",
            "February",
            "March",
            "April",
            "May",
            "June",
            "July",
            "August",
            "September",
            "October",
            "November",
            "December"
        ]
    },
    daysInMonth: [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31],
    firstDayOfWeek: 0
};

export default class DatePicker extends LightningElement {
    options = [];
    date;
    month;
    year;
    minDate;
    selectedDate;
    weekNameArray = l10n.weekdays.shorthand;
    keyValue = {
        startDate: {
            value: "",
            month: 0,
            year: 0,
            date: 0
        },
        endDate: {
            value: "",
            month: 0,
            year: 0,
            date: 0
        }
    };

    @track dAW = [];

    date = {
        current: {
            year: function () {
                return new Date().getFullYear();
            },
            month: {
                integer: function () {
                    return new Date().getMonth();
                }
            },
            day: function () {
                return new Date().getDate();
            }
        }
    };

    connectedCallback() {
        var currentDate;
        try {
            this.dAW = this.generatedAW();
            currentDate = new Date();
            this.setDateValues(currentDate, currentDate.getDate());
            this.generateYearOptions();
            this.generateMonth();
            this.date = currentDate.getDate();
        } catch (Err) {
            this.showToast('Error in JS', "Error in connectedCallback Method :" + Err, 'error', '');
        }
    }

    goToPreviousMonth() {
        this.changeMonth(-1);
        return false;
    }

    goToNextMonth() {
        this.changeMonth(1);
        return false;
    }

    handleYearChange(event) {
        var newYear;
        var date;
        var currentMonth;
        var currentYear;
        var currentDate;
        var targetDate;
        var daysInMonth;
        try {
            newYear = event.currentTarget.value;
            date = this.date;
            currentMonth = this.month;
            currentYear = this.year;
            if (!currentYear) {
                currentYear = this.date.current.year();
            }
            currentDate = new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, date);
            targetDate = new Date(newYear, currentDate.getMonth(), 1);
            daysInMonth = this.numDays(currentMonth, currentYear);
            if (daysInMonth < date) {
                // The target month doesn't have the current date. Just set it to the last date.
                date = daysInMonth;
            }
            this.setDateValues(targetDate, date);
            this.generateMonth();
        } catch (Err) {
            this.showToast('Error in JS', "Error in yearChange Method :" + Err, 'error', '');
        }
    }

    changeMonth(monthChange) {
        var currentYear;
        var currentMonth;
        var currentDay;
        var currentDate;
        var targetDate;
        var daysInMonth;
        try {
            currentYear = this.year;
            currentMonth = this.month;
            currentDay = this.date;
            currentDate = new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDay);
            targetDate = new Date(
                currentDate.getFullYear(),
                currentDate.getMonth() + monthChange,
                1
            );
            daysInMonth = this.numDays(currentMonth, currentYear);
            if (daysInMonth < currentDay) {
                // The target month doesn't have the current date. Just set it to the last date.
                currentDay = daysInMonth;
            }
            this.setDateValues(targetDate, currentDay);
            this.generateMonth();
        } catch (Err) {
            this.showToast('Error in JS', "Error in changeMonth Method :" + Err, 'error', '');
        }
    }

    goToToday() {
        var currentYear;
        var currentMonth;
        var currentDay;
        var targetDate;
        var keyV = this.keyValue;
        var todayV;
        try {
            currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
            currentMonth = parseInt(new Date().getMonth(), 10);
            currentDay = new Date().getDate();
            this.options.forEach(opt => {
                opt.selected = false;
                // eslint-disable-next-line eqeqeq
                if (opt ? opt.value == currentYear : false) {
                    opt.selected = true;
                }
            });
            targetDate = new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDay);
            this.setDateValues(targetDate, currentDay);
            todayV =
                currentYear +
                "-" +
                ("0" + (currentMonth + 1)).slice(-2) +
                "-" +
                ("0" + currentDay).slice(-2);
            keyV.startDate.value = keyV.endDate.value = todayV;
            keyV.startDate.month = keyV.endDate.month = currentMonth + 1;
            keyV.startDate.year = keyV.endDate.year = currentYear;
            keyV.startDate.date = keyV.endDate.date = currentDay;
            this.keyValue = keyV;
            this.generateMonth();
        } catch (Err) {
            this.showToast('Error in JS', "Error in goToToday Method :" + Err, 'error', '');
        }
    }

    generateYearOptions() {
        var dt;
        var startY;
        var endY;
        var years = [];
        var i;
        try {
            dt = new Date();
            startY = dt.getFullYear();
            endY = startY + 1;
            years = [];
            i = startY - 1;
            for (; i <= endY; i++) {
                years.push({ label: i, value: i, selected: i === startY });
            }
            this.options = years;
        } catch (Err) {
            this.showToast('Error in JS', "Error in generateYearOptions Method :" + Err, 'error', '');
        }
    }

    /**
     * Java style date comparisons. Compares by day, month, and year only.
     */
    dateEquals(date1, date2) {
        return date1 && date2 ? this.dateCompare(date1, date2) === 0 : false;
    }

    dateLessEquals(date1, date2) {
        return date1 && date2 ? this.dateCompare(date1, date2) <= 0 : false;
    }

    dateLess(date1, date2) {
        return date1 && date2 ? this.dateCompare(date1, date2) < 0 : false;
    }

    dateCompare(date1, date2) {
        var intVal = 0;
        try {
            if (date1.getFullYear() !== date2.getFullYear()) {
                intVal = date1.getFullYear() - date2.getFullYear();
            } else {
                if (date1.getMonth() !== date2.getMonth()) {
                    intVal = date1.getMonth() - date2.getMonth();
                } else {
                    intVal = date1.getDate() - date2.getDate();
                }
            }
        } catch (Err) {
            this.showToast('Error in JS', "Error in dateCompare Method :" + Err, 'error', '');
        }
        return intVal;
    }
    /**
     * generates the days for the current selected month.
     */
    generateMonth() {
        //var dayOfMonth = this.date;
        var month = this.month;
        var year = this.year;
        var minDate = this.minDate;
        var today = new Date();
        var d = new Date();
        var firstDayOfWeek = 0;
        var startDay;
        var i = 0;
        var j = 0;
        var k = 0;
        var tdClass;
        var dateStr;
        var array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
        var weekRem = 0;
        var dAW = this.dAW;
        var keyV = this.keyValue;

        try {
            d.setDate(1);
            d.setFullYear(year);
            d.setMonth(month);
            // java days are indexed from 1-7, javascript 0-6
            // The startPoint will indicate the first date displayed at the top-left
            // corner of the calendar. Negative dates in JS will subtract days from
            // the 1st of the given month
            firstDayOfWeek = 0; // In Java, week day is 1 - 7
            startDay = d.getDay();
            while (startDay !== firstDayOfWeek) {
                d.setDate(d.getDate() - 1);
                startDay = d.getDay();
            }
            for (; i <= 41; i++) {
                weekRem = i / 7;

                if (array1.includes(weekRem)) {
                    j++;
                    k = 0;
                }
                if (dAW[j].days[k]) {
                    tdClass = "";
                    if (d.getMonth() === month - 1 || d.getFullYear() === year - 1) {
                        dAW[j].days[k].ariaDisabled = true;
                        tdClass = "slds-disabled-text";
                    } else if (
                        d.getMonth() === month + 1 ||
                        d.getFullYear() === year + 1
                    ) {
                        dAW[j].days[k].ariaDisabled = true;
                        tdClass = "slds-disabled-text";
                    }
                    if (this.dateEquals(d, today)) {
                        tdClass += " slds-is-today";
                    }
                    if (
                        keyV.startDate.value && keyV.startDate.value
                            ? keyV.startDate.value === keyV.endDate.value
                                ? this.dateEquals(
                                    d,
                                    new Date(
                                        keyV.startDate.year,
                                        keyV.startDate.month - 1,
                                        keyV.startDate.date
                                    )
                                )
                                : false
                            : false
                    ) {
                        dAW[j].days[k].ariaSelected = true;
                        tdClass += " slds-is-selected";
                    } else if (
                        keyV.startDate.value
                            ? this.dateEquals(
                                d,
                                new Date(
                                    keyV.startDate.year,
                                    keyV.startDate.month - 1,
                                    keyV.startDate.date
                                )
                            )
                                ? true
                                : keyV.endDate.value
                                    ? this.dateLessEquals(
                                        d,
                                        new Date(
                                            keyV.endDate.year,
                                            keyV.endDate.month - 1,
                                            keyV.endDate.date
                                        )
                                    )
                                        ? !this.dateLessEquals(
                                            d,
                                            new Date(
                                                keyV.startDate.year,
                                                keyV.startDate.month - 1,
                                                keyV.startDate.date
                                            )
                                        )
                                        : false
                                    : false
                            : false
                    ) {
                        dAW[j].days[k].ariaSelected = true;
                        tdClass += " slds-is-selected slds-is-selected-multi";
                        if (!dAW[j].trClass) {
                            dAW[j].trClass =
                                "slds-has-multi-selection slds-has-multi-row-selection";
                        }
                    }
                    if (minDate && minDate.getTime() > d.getTime()) {
                        dAW[j].days[k].ariaDisabled = true;
                        tdClass = "slds-disabled-text";
                    }
                    dAW[j].days[k].label = d.getDate();
                    dAW[j].days[k].tdClass = tdClass;
                    dateStr =
                        d.getFullYear() +
                        "-" +
                        ("0" + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) +
                        "-" +
                        ("0" + d.getDate()).slice(-2);
                    dAW[j].days[k].value = dateStr;
                }
                d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
                k++;
            }
            this.dAW = dAW;
        } catch (Err) {
            this.showToast('Error in JS', "Error in generateMonth Method :" + Err, 'error', '');
        }
    }

    setDateValues(fullDate, dateNum) {
        try {
            this.year = fullDate.getFullYear();
            this.month = fullDate.getMonth();
            this.monthName = l10n.months.longhand[fullDate.getMonth()];
            this.date = dateNum;
            this.selectedDate = fullDate;
        } catch (Err) {
            this.showToast('Error in JS', "Error in setDateValues Method :" + Err, 'error', '');
        }
    }
    numDays(currentMonth, currentYear) {
        // checks to see if february is a leap year otherwise return the respective # of days
        return currentMonth === 1 &&
            ((currentYear % 4 === 0 && currentYear % 100 !== 0) ||
                currentYear % 400 === 0)
            ? 29
            : l10n.daysInMonth[currentMonth];
    }
    handleCellClick(event) {
        var theTarget;
        var key;
        var dateValue;
        var disabledFlag;
        try {
            theTarget = event.target;
            key = theTarget.getAttribute("data-id");
            dateValue = theTarget.getAttribute("data-value");
            disabledFlag = theTarget.getAttribute("data-disabled");
            if (disabledFlag ? disabledFlag === "true" : false) {
                // do Nothing Just Return
                return;
            }
            if (key && dateValue) {
                this.handleSelect(dateValue);
            }
        } catch (Err) {
            this.showToast('Error in JS', "Error in handleCellClick Method :" + Err, 'error', '');
        }
    }

    handleSelect(dateValue) {
        var keyValue;
        var strArry = [];
        try {
            keyValue = this.keyValue;
            strArry = dateValue.split("-");
            if (
                keyValue.startDate.value
                    ? keyValue.endDate.value
                        ? true
                        : this.dateLess(
                            new Date(strArry[0], strArry[1] - 1, strArry[2]),
                            new Date(
                                keyValue.startDate.year,
                                keyValue.startDate.month - 1,
                                keyValue.startDate.date
                            )
                        )
                    : true
            ) {
                keyValue.startDate.value = dateValue;
                keyValue.startDate.date = strArry[2];
                keyValue.startDate.month = strArry[1];
                keyValue.startDate.year = strArry[0];
                keyValue.endDate.value = "";
                keyValue.endDate.date = 0;
                keyValue.endDate.month = 0;
                keyValue.endDate.year = 0;
            } else if (keyValue.startDate.value && !keyValue.endDate.value) {
                keyValue.endDate.value = dateValue;
                keyValue.endDate.date = strArry[2];
                keyValue.endDate.month = strArry[1];
                keyValue.endDate.year = strArry[0];
            }
            this.keyValue = keyValue;
            this.generateMonth();
        } catch (Err) {
            this.showToast('Error in JS', "Error in handleSelect Method :" + Err, 'error', '');
        }
    }
    showToast(title, message, variant, mode) {
        var event = new ShowToastEvent({
            title: title,
            message: message,
            variant: variant,
            mode: (mode) ? mode : 'dismissable'
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(event);
    }

    generatedAW() {
        var tempArry = [];
        var tempdays = [];
        var i = 1;
        var j = 0;
        for (; i <= 6; i++) {
            tempdays = [];
            for (; j <= ((7 * i) - 1); j++) {
                tempdays.push({
                    label: "",
                    key: j,
                    ariaDisabled: false,
                    ariaSelected: false,
                    tdClass: "",
                    value: ""
                });
            }
            tempArry.push({
                name: "week" + i,
                trClass: "",
                days: tempdays
            });
        }
        return tempArry;
    }
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to make a [playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground) with the code there? That would help us debug this easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Datepicker is intended to be used as dropdown with a maximum supported width.
The Lightning Card wraps it in a flex container which leads to the fact that the styles are not playing together anymore.

See here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/IkQSZFOZk/1/edit

I just removed the lightning card and added the slds-dropdown class to the container - works.

If you want to have it for whatever reason bigger then the slds max style (20 rem) defaults i guess you have to write your own styles for the elements - because slds does not reflect this use case

Comment: Thanks @Renji-XD